# Anchor target _blank is blocked by browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to understand the following behaviour.

I have created a simple anchor tag:

```
<a href="/example/link" target="_blank">
    <img src="/images/layout_open.png">
    <span class="open-new-tab">Open in new tab</span>
</a>
```

**Update:** These `<a>` tags are created asynchronously. After an AJAX requests, the JS creates the `<a>` tags.

Problem is that Google Chrome will instead block the opening tab as if it was an obstrusive popup.

How can I avoid this behaviour?
I have read on other StackOverflow questions that I could add the `<a>` tag a data attribute and through jQuery bind an event to it and using JS I could open a new window.

What I cannot understand is why in my example it is not working, and in other sites it's not being blocked. It's linking to the same domain and host.

I concluded it can be because when I press the span or img, the event will be fired during bubbling phase, then, it is not a direct action, but an indirect action.

What's the cause of this and how can I avoid it?

Thanks

**Update:**

I think I have found out the solution. The problem is that the images have an onclick event attached to it I didn't earlier. Just like this:

```
<a href="/example/link" target="_blank">
    <img src="/images/layout_open.png" onclick="showFullImage()">
    <span class="open-new-tab">Open in new tab</span>
</a>
```

I haven't tried this yet, but as @Siderite suggested, that blocking was not regular browser behaviour. So I think that Google Chrome will mark this as an indirect action.

I will try tomorrow and let you know in Update nr. 2

Thank you all

Comment: It should work without problems.

Comment: Are you clicking it with code and not a user action?

Comment: After I click the image or the span. I do not click invoking the click event through Javascript.

Comment: Is there other code attached to the anchors?

Comment: I have found the solution. Finally it was because the images had an onclick event attached, so it would be detected as an indirect action instead. I haven't tried this yet, but I just found out that onclick event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the normal behaviour of a browser, but more likely an extension that tries to aggressively block popups.

Inspect your Chrome extensions by going to the chrome://extensions/ url.

Comment: My answer stands. No matter what changes the DOM, in the end you have an anchor element that contains an image and a span. Clicking on it should open the page in another window or tab. It is the default and very basic functionality of the browser. So either you have an extension blocking it, or there is some Javascript code executed when you click on it and that is what is blocked.

Comment: I stand with Siderite. Please disable all extensions and try running your code.